# Google Drive API for Mono for Android and MonoTouch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, google-drive-api

I just tried to use the given [.NET-DLL](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs) to connect to my google drive account with Mono for Android, but it failed.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2):
Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not
load assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android 
Profile?

Filename: "System.Web.dll"

at Monodroid.Tuner.MonoDroidResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference,
ReaderParameters parameters)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies,
AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies,
AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies,
AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies, 
AssemblyDefinition assembly)    
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (AndroidApp)
```

I add System.Web.dll to my shared library project, but it it makes no difference.

I can't also compile the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/), because some namespaces are unsupported.

**Have anyone an idea, how to use the google drive api with Mono for Android and MonoTouch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile from source.

The reason it doesn't work is that those compiler errors exist--these are real problems when trying to use it on Mono for Android.

You will have to find each issue and resolve it to use that library. See if there is a Silverlight version you can use as a starting point.